# Why are my objects gray?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Some of these pieces of rubble are a dark gray color, and won't texture properly. I can't figure out why. The normals are fine, there's no overlapping geometry, and even when I convert the tris to quads, the objects remain dark grey and won't texture normally. What did I do? These are sculpted, but so are the large, unaffected pieces with them. How can I fix this? :([image]

Comment: Oh my god, ha ha ha, how the hell did I miss that? Thank you! I obviously need more coffee today.

Comment: And you need to rename your folder to something different than Blender Shit! :)

Comment: Oh, ha ha. Whoops.

Comment: @HudsonVonMonkeytreat you can now mark answer as accepted.

Comment: How do I mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

The reason meshes are different is that darker mesh doesn't have **Material assigned** to it and brighter one has.

[image: material]